# par.rowIndex is null in this code

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to JavaScript but I can't find out why this program won't work.
I want when I click the dynamically created button which is situated in a cell in my dynamically created table to get the `rowindex` of the row in which the button is situated.

Thanks in advance - here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function whichrow(obj) {
                var par = obj.parentNode;
                while(par.nodeName.toLowerCase()! = 'tr') {
                    par = par.parentNode;
                }
                alert(par.rowIndex);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <script>
        mybody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        mytable = document.createElement("table");
        mytablebody = document.createElement("tbody");
        for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr"); 
            mycurrent_row.id = "row"+i;

            for(var j = 0; j<4; j++) {
                mycurrentcell = document.createElement("td");  
                currenttext = document.createTextNode("Row" + i + "Column" + j);
                mycurrentcell.appendChild(currenttext);
                mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrentcell);
            }   
            mybutoncell = document.createElement("td");
            but = document.createElement("button");
            mybutoncell.appendChild(but);

            mycurrent_row.appendChild(mybutoncell);

            mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
            but.onClick = whichrow(this);
        }
        mytable.appendChild(mytablebody);
        mybody.appendChild(mytable);

        mytable.setAttribute("border", "2"); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `but.onClick = whichrow(mycurrent_row);` in place of `but.onClick = whichrow(this);` ??

Comment: Also, put some space in the code `while(par.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {`...

Comment: What error are you getting in the console of firebug. Is it atleast loading this script on the page?

Comment: The same mistake - par is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so a few points to note here.

In the javascript eventing system, the system calls your callback with its own event object containing different properties according to what happened.

So, here are the mistakes:

1. When you're assigning to the event handler, when you say `but.onclick = whichrow(this)` you're setting but.onclick to the result of `whichrow`, which is `undefined` since you're not returning anything anyway. It should be `but.onclick = whichrow;` which will call `whichrow` when the user clicks your button. The parameter passed is a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) object. The [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) I've supplied should serve as a good start to read up on what kind of properties are available to you.
2. I have to check, since I use el.addEventListeners a lot, but `onclick` needs to be in lower case, not camelCase like you've done.
3. Inside the event callback, `this` usually refers to the element that was clicked, so you should use that.
4. There is no `rowIndex` property.

Now, trying to find a solution to your problem. rowIndex can be gleaned by traversing the dom. I'm not sure what purpose this will serve since you're creating the DOM by hand anyway and know the rowIndex already, but if it were unknown, here's what I would do

```
function whichRow(e) {
  // here this should be the button.
  var curRow = this.parentElement.parentElement,
      rowIndex = 0;

  while(curRow) {
    curRow = curRow.previousElementChild; 
    rowIndex++;
  }

  return rowIndex;
}
```

I'm writing this off the top of my head, but the point is to give the main idea. In the above snippet, I've taken the parent of the parent of the button, since here's the approximate markup of the button section:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <button></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

so, the parentElement of the parentElement of the button element should give you the `<tr>`. Then we'll traverse backwards till we don't have any previous elements, counting as we go. Once the previous element is null, return the count.

Comment: thanks I read a lot but it seems that something is missing! As I said I want to get the rowIndex property of the row in which the clicked button is situated!

Comment: 1.
You don't get to choose which object the click callback gets to be called with. It will depend on where the call is.

can you explain what you mean - I'm sorry I'm not so good in english

Comment: I'm ready with the problem!!!!First there is really no rowIndex property 2.onclick really should be with small letters here

Comment: OF course :) I wrtote that yesterday and it works perfectly! You were right - when i read more thing about tbhis word I managed to solve the problem Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The `obj` you are passing to `whichrow()` is a button, which I assume inside a `TD`. So your `while` loop will exit in its first iteration itself, resulting in `par` holding a `TD` - which does not have a property named `rowIndex`